# Unable to get String from JsonArray

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I am getting 2,3&4 string(values) in array but I am unable to set the values in textview. I am getting only 4 values in textview that is also the same repeat.Please tell me how to handle this.JSON below:

```
    {
    results: [
    {
    types: [
    "sublocality_level_3",
    "sublocality",
    "political"
    ]
    },
    {
    types: [
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ]
    },
    {
    types: [
    "travel_agency",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ]
    },
    {
    types: [
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ]
    },
    {
    types: [
    "store",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ]
    },
    {
    types: [
    "dentist",
    "health",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ]
    },
    {
    types: [
    "clothing_store",
    "store",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ]
    },
    {
    types: [
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment"
    ]
    },
    ]
    }
```

code what I am trying:

```
    try {
        object = new JSONObject(url);
        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject object1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray array1 = object1.getJSONArray("types");
            for(int j = 0; j < array1.length(); j++){
                if (array1.length()==2) {
                    t1 = array1.getString(0);
                    t2 = array1.getString(1);
                }  if (array1.length()==3) {
                    t1 = array1.getString(0);
                    t2 = array1.getString(1);
                    t3 = array1.getString(2);
                }  if (array1.length()==4) {
                    t1 = array1.getString(0);
                    t2 = array1.getString(1);
                    t3 = array1.getString(2);
                    t4 = array1.getString(3);
                }
            }

            getterSetter.setT1(t1);
            getterSetter.setT2(t2);
            getterSetter.setT3(t3);
            getterSetter.setT4(t4);
            list.add(getterSetter);
            adapter = new GooglePlacesAdapter(GooglePlace.this,list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I am not able to get string which are 2 & 3 in type arraylist

Comment: Re-edit your question. Your JSON file is not valid. [Please, read this link first](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a line similar to this

```
GetterSetter getterSetter = new GetterSetter();
```

Move this line inside the first for loop.

**Note:** There is absolutely no need of inner for loop (2nd). You can remove that loop and just keep the if statement inside it.

**Update:** Your code should be like

```
try {
    object = new JSONObject(url);
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
        JSONObject object1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray array1 = object1.getJSONArray("types");
        GetterSetter getterSetter = new GetterSetter(); // This line should be inside for loop
        if (array1.length()==2) {
            getterSetter.setT1(array1.getString(0));
            getterSetter.setT2(array1.getString(1));
        } else if (array1.length()==3) {
            getterSetter.setT1(array1.getString(0));
            getterSetter.setT2(array1.getString(1));
            getterSetter.setT3(array1.getString(2));
        } else if (array1.length()==4) {
            getterSetter.setT1(array1.getString(0));
            getterSetter.setT2(array1.getString(1));
            getterSetter.setT3(array1.getString(2));
            getterSetter.setT4(array1.getString(3));
        }

        list.add(getterSetter);
        adapter = new GooglePlacesAdapter(GooglePlace.this,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: the array which has 2 string is not responsive means i am not getting the values

Comment: rohit!! In this there are few fields. how to handle when i get 50-60 fields.

Comment: Your `GetterSetter` class should use an `ArrayList` rather than individual strings. That way you can simply keep on adding strings to that arraylist and at the end take action as required in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

fIRST array Should be in format Not in syntax

```
{
 "results": [
 {
   "types": [
  "sublocality_level_3",
"sublocality",
"political"
]
},
{
"types": [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
]
},
{
"types": [
"travel_agency",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
]
},
{
"types": [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
]
},
{
"types": [
"store",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
]
},
{
"types": [
"dentist",
"health",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
]
},
{
"types": [
"clothing_store",
"store",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
]
},
{
"types": [
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
]
}
]
}
```

In code You do this

```
try {
    object = new JSONObject(url);
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
        JSONObject object1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray array1 = object1.getJSONArray("types");
        for(int j = 0; j < array1.length(); j++){
            if (array1.length()==2) {
                t1 = array1.getString(0);
                t2 = array1.getString(1);
                t3 = "";
                t4 = "";
            }  else if (array1.length()==3) {
                t1 = array1.getString(0);
                t2 = array1.getString(1);
                t3 = array1.getString(2);
                t3 = "";
                t4 = "";
            }  else  if (array1.length()==4) {
                t1 = array1.getString(0);
                t2 = array1.getString(1);
                t3 = array1.getString(2);
                t4 = array1.getString(3);

            }
           getterSetter.setT1(t1);
           getterSetter.setT2(t2);
           getterSetter.setT3(t3);
           getterSetter.setT4(t4);
           list.add(getterSetter);
        }

        adapter = new GooglePlacesAdapter(GooglePlace.this,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this is Helpful for You